# Casting method to block in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm using a framework that uses a huge amount of block arguments to emit events. Due to licensing I can't release code samples, but I can still get my point across with similar code. Lets say you have the following code:

```
- (void)begin
{
    [MyService doSomething:^{
        NSLog(@"Done.");
    }];
}
```

This is fine, but the methods I'm dealing with have 14 block arguments, most of which take several parameters so it makes it very hard to read and difficult to test without creating repetitive boiler-plate code.

Is there a way I can point a block to an instance's method, something like:

```
- (void)doSomethingDelegate
{
    NSLog(@"Done.");
}

- (void)begin
{
    [MyService doSomething:CALLBACK(self, @selector(doSomethingDelegate))];
}
```

Where `CALLBACK` is a macro or native construct. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked into using [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/)?

Comment: You could just call a method from each of the blocks.  All the "ugly" code will be in one place and you can separate the logic into pieces.

Comment: Why not have methods that return blocks?

Comment: This actually does work in Swift (passing `self.someFunction` as a block captures a strong reference to `self`).

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can declare local blocks:

```
- (void)begin
{
    void (^callback)() = ^{ NSLog(@"Done."); };

    [MyService doSomething:callback];
}
```

You could extend that to:

```
- (void)callbackImpl {
    NSLog(@"Done.");
}

- (void)begin {
    void (^callback)() = ^() { [self callbackImpl]; };

    [MyService doSomething:callback];
}
```

And you could imagine a macro of the sort:

```
#define CALLBACK(name) void (^name)() = ^{ [self name##Impl]; };
```

It gets a little messier when you have arguments to the block, and you need to consider if you want a strong or weak reference to self in those blocks...

Comment: The first code sample is what I'm doing now, but it still has the major drawback that I can't mock out the callbacks to test if their firing. The second code sample is what I felt I was force to do, but thats the huge amount of boiler code I want to avoid.

Comment: I'd prefer a language (type safe) casting, but a macro will always be the fallback solution. I'm surprised it doesn't allow this...

Comment: Well, a block and selector invocation are two very different things.  I'm not saying it wouldn't be possible... but I'm not that surprised it's not a language feature.  It appears to be a feature of Swift, according to other commentators, so perhaps in that direction lies your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since I also have to worry about arguments that are in a different from this is the best solution I've found so far:

```
#define wrapper(args, method) ^args { [self method]; }

- (void)onUpdatingDeviceWithMessage:(NSString *)message progress:(float)progress
{
}

- (void)begin
{
    [MyService ...
        onUpdatingDevice:wrapper((NSString *message, float progress),
                                 onUpdatingDeviceWithMessage:message progress:progress)
}
```